# Meu if nunca cai no else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Eu preciso abaixar o volume do `<audio>` ao clicar na seta abaixo, mas o `if` não está funcionando, nunca entra no `else`. Por quê?

Código:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 

if ($("#nome").get(0).volume = 0.1)
{
    $("#nome").prop('muted', true);
}
else if ($("#nome").get(0).volume = 0.4)
{
    $("#nome").prop("volume", 0.1);
}

     }
});
```

Comment: Por estão negativando a questão, qual o motivo ?

Comment: @Fúlvio Eu acho que é porque o problema parece ter sido causado por uma distração (veja o uso correto de `==` no `if` de fora).

Comment: Concordo contigo @bfavaretto do erro, é isso ai, mas o intuito não é apontar os erros? Ou não?

Comment: @Fúlvio Um dos objetivos principais do site é ser um grande repositório de perguntas e respostas, idealmente úteis para mais de uma pessoa. Portanto, quanto mais chance a pergunta tiver de servir para futuros visitantes, que cheguem aqui pelo Google, melhor. Nesse sentido, erros de sintaxe assim não são bons candidatos. Editei o título com isso em mente.

Comment: Entendi @bfavaretto

Comment: Já está na hora da marcar a pergunta como resolvida

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Estou pensando em fechar... Mas estou em dúvida, porque esse tipo de erro  é até que comum.

Answer (score 6):

Você está usando `=` em vez de `==` (uma atribuição em vez de comparação):

```
if ($("#nome").get(0).volume == 0.1)
{
    $("#nome").prop('muted', true);
}
else if ($("#nome").get(0).volume == 0.4)
{
    $("#nome").prop("volume", 0.1);
}
```

Comment: vlw!!!!!!!!!!!!!!